# In Jenkins: pip install from git repo using SSH keys

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, pip, requirements.txt

In my Jenkins job, during the build phase, I execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Among my project's requirements, there are some paths to private git repositories, needing SSH keys to authenticate. I already created the keys (no passphrase), added the public key to the BitBucket server and the private key to Jenkins's credentials.

My project's code is pulled successfully with those same SSH keys (internally, Jenkins uses GIT_SSH), but pip doesn't know to pass them on to the server for authentication (the log shows: `Permission denied (publickey)`)

I've seen [Use SSH Key from Jenkins Git Plugin to Run Git Commands During Build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39647083/855395) , but it isn't answered. I've also seen some other talk about `Publish Over SSH` plugin, but I'm not sure it applies to me..

The build machine is Windows, by the way.

Automatically writing the private key to `<home_folder>\.ssh\id_rsa` seems like a security risk to me, though I might be wrong..?

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to use the same SSH keys it has to pip install ssh entries as well?

Comment: Another possible workaround that doesn't involve keys is to add your username/password to the Windows Credential Manager and use https instead of ssh. I had the exact same problem and this was by far the least time-consuming solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the [SSH Agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) to do this on Linux/Mac machines. The `pip install` command must go inside SSH agent's `withCredentials`. The plugin claims to support Windows (with some additional requirements), but I've never tried it.

I don't think I was able to have pip respect the `GIT_SSH` that Jenkins uses for the SCM step.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround:

- Make Jenkins clone the private repo containing the pip module, i.e. containing the `setup.py` file. Say the repo has been cloned to `/tmp/my_private_repo`
- Option 1: `cd /tmp/my_private_repo && pip install -e .`
- Option 2: `pip install git+file:///tmp/my_private_repo`  (note the 3 `///` after `file`)

Comment: I would edit your answer but the rules don't allow a single character fix. However @gogo_gorilla can fix the typo should be 'note the 3 ...' vs 'not the  3'.